# Magento 2 Admin Console - Performance Issues

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, sales-order, performance

For one of our big projects, our client is using the Magento backend Admin Console for their Project Managers to create orders/customers etc.

Our Customer has time and again reported that the performance of few screens like Order Listing, Create Order, Create/Edit Customer, Customer Listing screens etc. **in Magento Admin Console** is not up to the mark.

For Frontend, our team has already implemented Varnish. We have done JS/CSS minification etc.

**But beyond a point there isn't any major change in the backend performance, also we didn't find any specific performance enhancement recommendations for Magento Admin backend screens.
Any suggestions in this regard would be really helpful.**

Comment: Please do provide feedbacks if anyone has faced similar issues